# How to Click and Drag sprite on Y Axis only in Cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, click, drag

I was wondering if somebody could help me out and possibly point me in the right direction.

Here's my code:

```
- (void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:point];
    sprite.position = ccp (sprite.x, point.y);
}
```

Here's what I'm trying to do.

I want to click and drag the sprite up and down on the Y axis only.  I want the sprite to at close to the top of the screen, which is in portrait mode.

I don't want the 'popping' or 'skipping' around every time you touch the screen in a different spot.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use vectors. This codesample uses the targeted touch delegate instead of the standard. Make newPos x property always the same to achieve your behavior.

```
- (void)panForTranslation:(CGPoint)translation {    
    if (selSprite) {
        CGPoint newPos = ccpAdd(selSprite.position, translation);
        selSprite.position = newPos;
    }
}

- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {       
    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

    CGPoint oldTouchLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view];
    oldTouchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:oldTouchLocation];
    oldTouchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:oldTouchLocation];

    CGPoint translation = ccpSub(touchLocation, oldTouchLocation);    
    [self panForTranslation:translation];    
}
```